# Textview only showing last item from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I'm trying to use the textview to display the contact that was selected from the listview. The listview contains contacts that was selected by the user from the android phonebook which are loaded into the listview. The textview will only show the last item in the listview, even though the user has selected another contact which wasn't the last contact in the listview.

Even though in my log prints, I can see which contact I have selected but it still defaulting to the last contact when I try to print it out onto a textview in another window.

[image: Contacts List]
[image: Text Display]

**addModem.java**

```
 display_contacts1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Object o = adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
            String str_text = o.toString();

            String name = AddModem.name;
            String phoneNumber = AddModem.phoneNo;

            Log.e("Contacts selected", str_text);

            // Display string here showing which contact was selected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str_text + " Selected for Communication", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // Update Modem View Contact
            modemView.setText(str_text);

            //modemView.setText(name);
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            // Go back to the main screen after the contact has been selected
            Intent main_menu = new Intent(AddModem.this, MainActivity.class);
            main_menu.putExtra("StrValue", str_text);
            startActivity(main_menu);

        }

    });
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
// This checks to see if the current contact is selected
        if ( display_contacts.isEmpty())
        {
            number = null;

            // No contacts selected from the Add Modem listview
            modemView.setText("No contact selected");
        }
        else
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
            {
                // This is not updating to the one selected
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    modemView.setText(name);
                    Log.e("DisplayName", name);
                }
            });

        }
```

Comment: Why do you start `AddModem` activity twice in `onItemClick`?

Comment: Disregard that, that line only needs to be called once, I've edited the sample code

Comment: Does the log `Log.e("Contacts selected", str_text);` prints correct value? Another thing, could you try removing `arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`? Also I would like to see how you get the value for `name`

Comment: The Log.e("Contacts selected", str_text); prints out the correct value that the user selected from the listview. When I commented out arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();, it was still printing out the last value in the listview.

Comment: The way I'm getting the name is from the android phone book                                        int  nameIndex =cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

Comment: name = cursor.getString(nameIndex);

Comment: What is the `cursor` here? It should be `name = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue")` in `onCreate()` method!

Comment: name = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue"), is this under public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View view, int position, long id)

Comment: What do you mean? under `onItemClick`, you put the string in, so in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`, you need to get it out with `getStringExtra`

Comment: I got it working, in the onItemClick function, I have modemView.setText(str_text) and in the mainActivity I have the line name = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue");

Comment: Yup, exactly what I suggested above :)

Answer (score 0):

In the main activity code we needed

```
name = getIntent().getStringExtra("StrValue");
```

before we printed it out on the textView

```
modemVide.setText(name);
```